# Capturing HTTP request URL with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

New guy around here with a really bad workaround scenario:

1. I'm a digital marketer with no access to my client's CMS.
2. Their contract developer added Facebook tracking to product pages but forgot to add product ID.
3. The contractor is currently AWOL so I can't get him to fix this immediately.
4. I found that some of their HTTP requests contain product ID.
5. So before we can get it fixed, I'm trying to capture these HTTP requests and save the ID as a query fragment variable by adding an event listener in GTM, and then use GTM (again) to send a proper tracking request.

Is there a piece of sample code that you would recommend?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Has the developer done the tagging in GTM or has he hardcoded it?
If it's in GTM then update the tags and publish it, if it's hardcoded the best bet is to go and change it.
If you don't have access and it isn't done in GTM then the inadvisable route is trying to monkey patch the facebook tracking script to include the code, not a job for the faint of heart.